# PHPUnit: exclude two or more namespaces using the --filter option

Tags: regex, filter, phpunit, pcre

I need to exclude several namespaces from my local unit tests execution. This is because I don't have some services in my local environment that are available in the CI pipeline. I can include a namespace by running something like:

```
phpunit --filter 'MyApp\\Providers\\Provider1'
```

I understand that the `filter` option accepts regular expressions, as described in https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/textui.html#command-line-options . However, I'm not being able to find a valid one to exclude two or more namespaces.

Tried different combinations like:

```
phpunit --filter '(?!(MyApp\\Providers\\Provider1)|(MyApp\\Services\\Service1)).*'
```

which is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specified look ahead starting position. So it will consume whole line from 0 to length of line content.

For example, if there's 3 lines with `a1`, `a2`, `a3` and used `(?!(a1|a2)).*`, result will be `1`, `2`, `a3`.

Because you only skip 0 position of two lines (before `a1` and `b1`).

If you specify starting position like `^(?!(a1|a2)).*`, result will be only `a3`.

Because look ahead apply from only start of line(`^`) and `.*` will consume whole line.

https://regex101.com/r/bBEUOD/1

Comment: You saved me hours of attempts. Thank you!